# I want to improve a jQuery navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am a noob in jQuery, and I need help. I arrived to do a simple navigation, with this HTML code:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
        <a class="tab-link" href="#">SPECS</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <a href="#">Specs 1</a>
            <a href="#">Specs 2</a>
            <a href="#">Specs 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <a class="tab-link" href="#">GALLERY</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <a href="#">Gallery 1</a>
            <a href="#">Gallery 2</a>
            <a href="#">Gallery 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <a class="tab-link" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <a href="#">Projects 1</a>
            <a href="#">Projects 2</a>
            <a href="#">Projects 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <a class="tab-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <a href="#">Contact 1</a>
            <a href="#">Contact 2</a>
            <a href="#">Contact 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I got this jQuery code:

```
$(".tab-link").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").toggleClass("visible");
});
```

The .sub-menu is hidden in css, and .visible class is just `display:block;`

It's working great, but I got a problem. If I click the first menu item, it opens the sub menu correctly. But if I click another item, it will open the submenu over the first sub menu. I have to click the submenu parent which I clicked earlier, to close it. I want it to be simplier, if a submenu is already opened, when I click another parent, it will first hide all the .sub-menus with the visible class, and than add the .visible class to that sub menu. I hope I am clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to remove the `active` class of any `sub-menu` with the `active` class

```
$(".tab-link").click(function () {
    $(".tabs .sub-menu.visible").removeClass("visible");
    $(this).next().addClass("visible");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just add `$('.sub-menu').removeClass('visible');` right before your show code. It will hide all the .sub-menu instances and show the needed one.

```
$(".tab-link").click(function () {
    $('.sub-menu').removeClass('visible');
    $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").toggleClass("visible");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply remove the visible class from all the elements, since you want to toggle it, so you need to remove it from everything *but* the menu item that's been clicked.  That way you can still toggle a clicked menu item on and off.

http://jsfiddle.net/KYmcP/

```
$(".tab-link").click(function () {
    var $tab = $(this).closest(".tab");
    $(".tab").not($tab).find(".sub-menu").removeClass("visible");
    $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").toggleClass("visible");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clean solution, but it's what you need, I hope.

```
$('.tab-link').click(function () {
    var $subMenu = $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu');

    if($subMenu.hasClass('visible')) {
        $('.visible').removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        $('.visible').removeClass('visible');
        $subMenu.addClass('visible');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8CJDJ/1/